# Why doesn't grub-emu launch on a separate window?

Tags: terminal, boot-loader

When I run grub-emu it launches within the terminal, and not as a separate window, which doesn't allow to inspect theming.

I have checked it is compiled with SDL2, but it doesn't seem to work. It launches as CLI.

Comment: I've never used grub-emu before and the documentation barely mentions it. Perhaps sdl is a video module you have to load in your grub.cfg first? I use virtualization to test Grub, just pass the drive readonly to Qemu/KVM, with network disabled just in case... on Github there is also a script grub2-theme-preview that generates a bootable grub image on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

In  "grub.cfg"  you  can  toggle  using  the graphical versus the terminal output with the command "terminal_output [output]", where output can be "gfxterm", "console" or both.